# why the templates still not changing when something change in models in django?

Tags: python, django

My Django project has the Credits System inside of it.
I want the templates change if the user has not enough credits.

> models.py

```
class CreditSystem(models.Model):
    forUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delte=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    credits = mdoels.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
```

> views.py

```
def userPanel(request):
    credits = CreditSystem.objects.get(forUser=request.user)
    return render(request, 'user/panel.html', {'credit': credit.credit}
```

> user/panel.html

```
{% if credit < 5 %}
<p>You have insufficient Credits</p>
{% else %}
<p> Welcome! </p>
{% endif %}
```

Now for example, I change the user credits at 10 (at the admin panel).
Then it shows the "**Welcome!**" message at the html.
Now if I change the current user credits at 5. How the templates change the message to "**you have insufficient credit**" message without Reloading it? I can do it with javascript stuff (perform a request per second) but it's to dirty to use that method.

Do I need a make it Asynchronous using django-channels?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : I stuck with the only thing I knew at the time I wrote this answer, which is client-to-server requests. `Django Channels` might be a good way to answer OP's question.

---

Yes, one way or another, you will have to call the view which gives you the number of credits if you want to adapt what's shown to the connected user. There are 2 ways to do so, and you identified both of them:

- you can reload the page, so the whole template will be rendered again,
- or you can use javascript which will call a view returning you the number of credits (`get_credit_view` returning a json array for instance). Then, it is to your js logic to adapt the page to the user (but the template will be rendered only once on serverside).

Comment: so in short. There's no solution or method for the serverside for soliving this?

Comment: what about the WebSockets? Django-Channels?

Comment: Well I made a little research, and it looks like it could be possible to push data from server to client effectively in Django. django-channels seems to be a good way to go! I will investigate furthermore for my own sake, as I did not know about that solution. Both ways to do so must be studied, I think the server-to-client thing could be a little bit more difficult to do than calling the server from client. Thanks for gibing me things to read!